How do I iterate through a dictionary which has nested dictionaries to compare each nested dictionary to an input dictionary?
Example:
input_dict = {1:23, 2:34, 3:45, 4:56}
nested_dict = {'one':{1:23}, 'two':{1:23, 2:34}, 'three':{1:23, 2:34, 5:67}}

The ultimate goal is to compare input_dict to each of the nested dictionaries in nested_dict and create a list of the keys of nested_dict where any of the input_dict keys and values completely match all of the nested_dict keys and values. It should ignore anything extra in input_dict.
In the example above, the output would be:
['one', 'two']

I found a way to compare two dictionaries with:
all(
  key in input_dict and nested_dict[key] == input_dict[key] 
  for key in nested_dict
)


You were close.  Iterate the nested_dict items and check each nested dictionary.  Collect the keys of the ones that all match the input_dict:
input_dict = {1:23, 2:34, 3:45, 4:56}
nested_dict = {'one':{1:23}, 'two':{1:23, 2:34}, 'three':{1:23, 2:34, 5:67}}

keys = [key for key, nested in nested_dict.items()
        if all(k in input_dict and nested[k] == input_dict[k] for k in nested)]

print(keys)

Output:
['one', 'two']


If we use dict.get we can avoid the check for the key being in input_dict.
keys = [
  key 
  for key, val in nested_dict.items() 
  if all(val.get(k) == input_dict.get(k) for k in val)
]

Of course, there is a corner case where this fails. If a dictionary in nested_dict has a key where the associated value is None, and the key doesn't exist in input_dict, then dict.get will return None and there will be a match that we didn't intend.
If we break this down a bit further, you need to determine two things:

That the nested dictionary's keys form a subset of the keys in input_dict.
That for each of those keys, the associated value matches the value in input_dict.

We might express this using set intersection.
keys = [
  key 
  for input_key_set in (set(input_dict),) 
  for key, nested in nested_dict.items()
  for nested_key_set in (set(nested),)
  if input_key_set & nested_key_set == nested_key_set
  if all(input_dict[k] == nested[k] for k in nested_key_set)
]

